# Numpy vstack: Key Error 0 for dataframes with 1 row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My software works 99% of the time, but I found a bug that crashes the program if the pandas dataframe has one row

```
def prep(df):        
    X = np.vstack(np.asarray((df['col1'],df['col2']),order='C',dtype='float')).T
    return df,X
```

Now I get this error when the function is called

```
KeyError: 0
```

I'm not sure what's going on, but noticed that it gives this error only when `df` has one row. Anything greater than 1 row works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the function above a long time ago. I learned better python now

this is the solution for future folks

```
def prep(df):
    X = df[['col1','col2']].as_matrix()
    return df,X
```